# Hibernate: DDL<-> Classes, which direction?

Tags: hibernate

What do you think is the "right" way to use Hibernate? To design the model at the object level (classes) and then to generate the DDL from it? To design the model at the relational level (tables) and then to generate the classes from it?

What are the pros and cons of each method?

In the case the DDL is created first, you generate the classes from it and then you may add some code in the classes, what happens when you want to add a new column to a table for example, you have to modify the class respectively. Manually? Does Hibernate provide a tool to modify the class without regenerating the class entirely (removing the custom code)?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer the following approach:

- At the early stages of the project you design classes and generate DDL from them, so that you can easily change your domain model as often as you need.

  However, when designing a domain model you still need to keep the database schema in mind, in order to avoid creating a model that would lead to inefficient database access.
- As project evolves and domain model becomes more stable, you can begin to maintain database schema as a separate artifact. It simplifies fine tuning of indexes and constraints.

  At this stage you need to keep you schema in sync with the domain model manually, but it's needed anyway because automatic DDL updates provided by Hibernate are not reliable enough for use in production, so that you need to keep track of your changes and write migration scripts for them.

Comment: +1. If you know how Hibernate works, designing entities or designing tables is the more or less the same thing anyway, and you should never forget that your objects must be mapped to tables somehow, and that queries must be efficient.

Answer (score 2):

I would generate the domain classes first and then use Hibernate to create the DDL.

This is because this allows you to specify the associations between tables (ManyToOne etc.) which will lead to appropriate foreign keys being created. You can also use annotations to specify unique indexes which will be reflected in the generated DDL.

However, once your project is stable you should not use hibernate to upgrade your schema following changes to your domain class.